# Preventing direct access to a page in Next.js while allowing access from within the app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

I'm working on a Next.js application, and I have a specific page, let's call it "thank-you," that I want to prevent users from accessing directly via the URL. However, I want to allow access to this page only through internal navigation within the app, such as clicking a button.

I've tried using a middleware function to redirect direct requests to the home page, and it works as expected. However, when I try to navigate to the "thank-you" page using client-side routing (e.g., router.push("/thank-you")), it still triggers the middleware and redirects to the home page.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

Middleware Function (middleware.ts):

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/thank-you"],
};
```

Button Click Handling (YourComponent.tsx):

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    router.push("/thank-you");
  };
...
}
```

How can I prevent direct access to the "thank-you" page while allowing access through internal navigation within the app?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

*UPDATE*

I tried with `getServerSideProps` and still have the same problem.
Redirect to home happens from button click as well.

```
export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  return {
    redirect: {
      permanent: false,
      destination: "/",
    },
    props: {},
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to check the request referer in your middleware ? I guess you can check if the Referer header value is similar to the requested URL (meaning you are trying to access /thank-you from your application), and redirect to the home page only if it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing about seems to work for you, probably you might want to consider one the following:

#### Check referrer

The idea is to limit pages the user can come from for the page you mentioned.

The code might look like this:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = (context) => {
  if (!context.req.headers.referer.contains(WHITE_LISTED_URLS)) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/",
      },
      props: {},
    };
  };

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

I just need to warn you that the user still can bypass this check, so it won't work if you need to have more secure solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer, instead of WHITE_LISTED_URLS, since they can multiple, I just added a string "internalNavigation=true" and checked 
const isInternalNavigation = 

  if (!req.headers.cookie?.includes(
    "internalNavigation=true"
  );) {
...

And it works fine. I mean the idea is the same like you suggested.

But I am still curious how to do that with middleware.
Thank you anyways

Comment: @FD3 I've added an answer that uses the referer header idea in middleware. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77645498/3982562

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header like the [answer of Ilya Khrustalev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77639659/3982562) suggests. To do this using middleware, you can simply check if the referer origin matches the request origin. Aka the request is coming from your own site.

Note that the Referer header is normally set by the web-browser, but can be manually set by a user. So this is not the way to go regarding security. However if you simply want to redirect a user back when pasting an URL in the address bar this would do fine. **Just realize that whatever is located at the URL is still public.**

With the warning out of the way let's get to the code.

```js
// middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export const config = { matcher: '/thank-you' };

export function middleware(request) {
  try {
    const requestURL = new URL(request.url);
    const refererURL = new URL(request.headers.get("referer"));

    if (refererURL.origin !== requestURL.origin) {
      throw new Error("origin mismatch");
    }
  } catch {
    // executed if one of the URLs fails to parse, or if origin doesn't match
    NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
  }
}
```

Since `new URL(request.headers.get("referer"))` can failed to parse if the Referer header is not given or invalid I've used a try-catch statement for the redirect.

For additional info about multiple/dynamic route matches see the [Next.js Middleware documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like auth-guard issue. Add AuthGuard in root folder. If using app Router it would be layout, and control access with redux or other state management.

I didn't include but you also should change authRights.thankYou to false in auth guard or in thank you page.

**Root Layout**

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: IPageParamsLayout) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
       <main>
        <AuthGuard>{children}</AuthGuard>
       </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**AuthGuard**

```
"use client"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

// Authguard would have all redirection logic to keep redirection in one place and prevent redirection loop.
const AuthGuard = (children) => {
const pathname = usePathname();
const router = useRouter();
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
const authRights = useAppSelector(authRights);

  if(pathname === 'thank-you' && !authRights.thankYou) {
   router.push(`/`);
  }

  return (
    <>{children}</>
  )
}
export default AuthGuard
```

**Component that redirects to Thank you.**

```
"use client"

const BeforeThankYou = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  return (
    <div onClick={() => {
      dispatch(setAuthRights({
       thankYou: true
       }))
     router.push("/thank-you")
    }}>Click to Thank You Page</div>

  )
}
export default BeforeThankYou
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit too simple, but why expose a route to the component when don't want it accessible via a direct URL?

The simplest solution is to avoid the issue entirely and not expose an URL for the "thank you" page. You can do this by creating a `<ThankYou />` component, and render that on the current page as part of some procedure.

This can be done by toggling some state (`showThankYou` for example):

```
export default function Page() {
  const [showThankYou, setShowThankYour] = useState(false);

  // ...

  if (showThankYou) return <ThankYou />;

  return (
    <NormalPage />
  );
}
```

Or by returning it as part of a more complicated process:

```
export enum SignUp {
  None,
  UserInfo,
  ThankYou,
}

export default function Page() {
  const [signUp, setSignUp] = useState(SignUp.None);
  const [_context, setContext] = useState({});
  const context = useMemo(() => ({ ..._context, setContext }), [_context]);

  const navigateSignUp = useCallback(() => setSignUp(SignUp.UserInfo), []);
  const navigateThankYou = useCallback(() => setSignUp(SignUp.ThankYou), []);

  switch (signUp) {
    case SignUp.UserInfo:
      return <CollectUserInfo {...context} navigateThankYou={navigateThankYou} />;
    case SignUp.ThankYou:
      return <ThankYou {...context} />;
    default:
      return <InformationPage {...context} navigateSignUp={navigateSignUp} />;
  }
}
```

Because this doesn't expose a route to the "thank you" page, users can only get there by following the procedure.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually that would be also an option, but I have an requirement to have a separate `thank-you`  page.